# Angular 5 DomSanitizer with Hyperlinks

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink, ckeditor

I am using a WYSIWYG editor (CKEditor) and trying to render the content with Angular 5.

What I am trying to figure out is the proper way to use DomSanitizer in Angular 5. The problem I am facing is that Hyperlinks are not working (are not "clickable") in the resulting sanitized HTML.

I am using the following Typescript code to return a safeHtml content:

```
 public getSafeContent(): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.page.content);
}
```

and using it in my template this way:

```
<div [innerHTML]="getSafeContent()"></div>
```

This will render the HTML with all inline styles intact, but hyperlinks won't work.

I tried doing this instead:

```
public getSafeContent(): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.page.content);
}
```

Which results in that Hyperlinks actually works, but inlines styles are not.

Is there a way to get both styles and hyperlinks to work with sanitized content?

**Update**

This is what the page looks like in Chrome dev tools:

```
<div _ngcontent-c22="" class="row">
   <div _ngcontent-c22="" class="col-lg-12">

        <div _ngcontent-c22="">
            <p><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the google link is not clickable.

Comment: What hyperlinks? What does the context look like?

Comment: Have you tried [bypassSecurityTrustHtml](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml) instead of `sanitize()`?

Comment: typical context that does not work is: 
       <p><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></p>

and yes I have tried bypassSecurityTrustHtml

Comment: What does the resulting DOM look like?

Comment: The DOM looks correct, but Angular is blocking all links that are external to the site. If I use relative links it works. It seems like I have to extract the urls from the content and pass them through the bypassSecurityTrustUrl  and then add it back to the content again to make it work, which is not ideal.

Comment: I'm sure that's not the case. If it's a correct link in the DOM, it will work. Can you please copy the link HTML from the browsers DOM from devtools to your question?

Answer (score 2):

`bypassSecurityTrustHtml` allows `<script>` tags in the content.  For URLs you need  `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`.  See here: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustUrl.

I've never tried stacking the `bypassXXX` methods, so I don't know if you can do something like this `bypassSecurityTrustUrl(bypassSecurityTrustHtml(myContent))` but I would guess probably not since each method takes a string but returns an object (of type `SafeHtml/SafeUrl`), so it can't be used as the input to the stacked function call which expects a string.

So, you may need to parse the contents, pass each URL into the `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` and then combine everything back together again.

**Update**

I just looked at the sanitize method.  I haven't tried this, but something like this might work:

```
this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(myContent));
```

since `sanitize` can take a `SafeValue` as an input.  The inner `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` sanitizes the URLs and returns a `SafeUrl`, which is unwrapped by the outer sanitize and used as input to make it HTML safe.  Like I said, I haven't tried it, but it looks good in theory...

Comment: bypassSecurityTrustUrl() will complain if it has HTML tags, so I could not pass the whole content to this function. If I extract just the urls and add it to the content it works.
If I use this function direcly:  this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, myContent); links work, but inline styles are wiped.

Answer (score 2):

in .ts pipe for 'URL' sanitizer

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeUrl' })
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

in .html

```
<div [innerHTML]="Content | sanitizeUrl| sanitizeHtml">
                    </div>
```

pipe for 'HTML' sanitizer

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

Please consider the above solution. this will apply both pipes without disturbing any style and link click event at same time

Answer (score 0):

I used DOMPurify library to sanitize the DOM. DOMPurify is a DOM-only, super-fast, uber-tolerant XSS sanitizer for HTML, MathML and SVG.

I created angular PureTextPipe pipe to sanitize the raw content

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

@Pipe({
  name: 'pureText',
  pure: true
})
export class PureTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(str: any): any {
    let res = str;
    if (str === null || str === undefined || str === '' || str === 0) {
      res = '--';
    }
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(res);
  }
}
```

Now to use this pipe you just need to add it to HTML like:

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourRawData | pureText"></div>
```

Documentation of DOMPurify at

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution to this. With this both the URL and the style would work.  It is again with the use of "bypassSecurityTrustHtml". It's surprising how using this in html or TS does not make the link work, but using this in a seperate file as a pipe makes this work like a charm.

Here is what I did

1. Create a Custom Pipe

.safe.dom.pipe

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeResourceUrl, SafeScript, SafeStyle, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
@Pipe({
name: 'safeDom'
 })
export class SafeDomPipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}`
```

2. In Case you have a common module in your project that is included where you require to implement it, you can declare and export this package from there. Else just declare this pipe in the module you want to implement this.

> ```
>   import { SafeDomPipe } from './pipes/safe.dom.pipe';
>     @NgModule({
>         imports: [
>             .....
>         ],
>         exports: [
>           ....
>           SafeDomPipe 
>           ....
>         ],
>         declarations: [
>           ....
>           SafeDomPipe 
>           ....
>         ])
> ```

Now in Html you can directly use this pipe.

```
<div [innerHtml]="data | safeDom: 'html' "> </div>
```

This would allow both link and style.

Comment: And what does this do with the security of your application?!

Answer (score 0):

If you're data content is consisting of HTML with Hyperlinks. But we want to sanitize with hyperlink working. This worked for me:

HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="getSafeContent()"></div>
```

TS:

```
public getSafeContent(): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.page.content);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

Component:

```
content = '<b>Hello World</b><p style=\'font-size:14pt\'>
<a href=\'http://www.google.com\'>Go to Google</a></p>Test123';

public getSafeContent(): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.content);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="getSafeContent()"></div>
```

Link works and inline styles are intact

Comment: I just tested your example and the link is not working for me by just clicking it. It works if I right-click and select open in a new tab, but not left clicking it. If I insert the same HTML directly in the template the link works as expected. What angular version are you using? I am running 5.1.1.