# How to Sanitize Contenteditable inner text : Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently I have div which is `contenteditable` and I am using input method to grab the inner text from that div.

If I paste any HTML or URL in the `contenteditable` div then the automatically showing up the span tags and it's related css. I have tried to use a pipe from this link - [Angular 5 DomSanitizer with Hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788809/angular-5-domsanitizer-with-hyperlinks).

It is throwing an errr - `SafeValue must use [property]=binding: (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

**QUESTION** - Is there any way to sanitize the innertext value of the contenteditable if there is any html or url either we write or paste.

```
<div class="text-block" contenteditable="true" #textElement (input)="onTextChange($event.target.innerText)" [innerText]="Content | sanitizeUrl| sanitizeHtml"></div>


public Content : string;

onTextChange(value: string) {
  console.log(value);
  this.Content  = value;
}
```

Comment: can you post the component code ?

Comment: @pbachman I already did, from public in code block.

Comment: If you want an answer "for the latest Angular" I highly suggest you remove the reference to Angular 8 in the title...

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml',
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(dirtyhtml) {
    const sanitizedHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyhtml);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sanitizedHtml);
  }
}
```

Can you try with this pipe?

or try this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same problem without using pipes and do the conversion from the ts file itself, so the
`html` code will be like

```
<div
  class="text-block bordered"
  [style.border]="'5px solid black'"
  contenteditable="true"
  #textElement
  (change)="onTextChange($event?.target?.innerText)"
  [innerText]="Content"
></div>
```

and `ts` file will be

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public Content: SafeHtml = '<p> test </p>';
  constructor(private readonly domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    //
  }

  onTextChange(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    this.Content = this.getInnerHTMLValue(value);
  }

  getInnerHTMLValue(value: string) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

here the html sanitizer is called on change event from component function and can add more logic in it if needed to include url and other values too.

hope this solves your problem :)

PS: ignore the style, it is just for making visibility to the div element.

link to stalkblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-jsl3t5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)